# Laravel 5 Protecting Assets With .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I have an asset folder in my public directory that isn't protected by the .htaccess file. Currently, I am just using static index.html pages inside the assets folders but I'd like a proper way to redirect. I don't know much about .htaccess so any help will be much appreciated.

My current .htaccess inside public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: If you don't want to show the contents of directories, simply remove the third last line containing `!-d`.

Comment: @MikeRockett Thanks a lot. It works now. I just signed up, so I don't think I can upvote yet. Thanks again!

Comment: I'll add my comment as an aswer which you'll be able to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show the contents of directories, simply remove this line:

```bash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

In this context, the last three lines of your file are used to say, "if the incoming request does not match an existing directory or file, then rewrite the request to `index.php` for processing."

So when you remove the line mentioned above, it will pass any request to a directory to `index.php`. However, files inside such directory will still be served, due to the remaining condition.